# Seeking the definition of לופפת

Tags: words, translation

What would the translation of לופפת be?

As in השאיפה להכרת האמת לופפת את לב האדם ואת מוחו

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: פרקי אמונה השקפה והנהגה על פי ספרי מרן החזון איש

Comment: Ever go to a schwarma place and ask for a "lafa"? It's wrapped around the meat. Some sifrei Torah have a letter Pei that continues to spiral inwards, "Pei lefufa."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate it as follows:

> The desire/aspiration to know the truth, **envelops / clings to** the human heart and mind.

When talking about the various blemishes / defects of a Kohen, the verse in [Vayikra 21:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.21.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0) writes:

> אֽוֹ־גִבֵּ֣ן אוֹ־דַ֔ק א֖וֹ תְּבַלֻּ֣ל בְּעֵינ֑וֹ א֤וֹ גָרָב֙ א֣וֹ **יַלֶּ֔פֶת** א֖וֹ מְר֥וֹחַ אָֽשֶׁךְ׃
>
> or who is a hunchback, or a dwarf, or who has a growth in his eye, or who has a boil-scar, or **scurvy**, or crushed testes.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Leviticus.21.20.4?lang=bi) analyses the word used to describe scurvy and writes as follows:

> גרב וילפת — These are kinds of boil; גרב is identical with חרס (mentioned in Deuteronomy 28:27) — a boil which is dry both inside and on the surface. ילפת is identical with the Egyptian lichen, (חזזית) ([Sifra, Emor, Section 3 15](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Emor%2C_Section_3.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). **Why is it called ילפת (root לפת “to embrace")? Because it continues to cling to the body until the day of death**. It is wet on the surface and dry inside. In another passage, however, Scripture gives the name גרב to a boil which is wet on the surface and dry inside, as it is said (Deuteronomy 28:27) "[The Lord will smite thee…] ובגרב ובחרס”, where גרב necessarily denotes a wet boil since חרס (identical with חרש, potsherd) denotes the dry species. But the explanation is as follows: חרס always denotes the dry skin disease, ילפח always the wet one; as to גרב it depends: When Scripture mentions גרב together with חרס it is calling a ילפת by the term ,גרב and when it mentions it (גרב) together with ילפת (as is the case here) it is calling a חרס by the term גרב. Thus is it explained in [Bekhorot 41a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bekhorot.41a.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

So, the term is used to imply something that "hugs" and encircles the object, in this case the skin condition "clings" to the body until the day of death.

In a similar context, when the Shulchan Aruch details the things that invalidate an esrog - one of the disqualifying features are boils. Indeed in [OC 648:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.648.9?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) when introducing the notion of a חזזית (boil) the text writes two definitions in parenthesis - "תרגום או **ילפת** או חזזן".

As the SA develops the concept in [OC 648:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.648.13?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) the [Shaarei Teshuva](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27arei_Teshuvah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.648.22?lang=bi) explains why the word ילפת is an appropriate synonym bringing the Gemara in Bechoros cited above, and notes as follows:

> וכן איתא בבכורות דף מ"א ילפת זו חזזית המצרית ואמר ר"ל שמלפפת והולכת כו' פירש"י מלפפת דבוקה בו כדמתרגמינן ויחבר וילפף ע"ש וענין דבוק בו...
>
> And similarly it is brought in Bechoros 41a the word "ילפת" - this is the boils that the Egyptians were afflicted with, and Reish Lakish says (why is it then called "ילפת"?) as it grabs [melapefes] continuously. [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Bekhorot.41a.7.6?lang=bi) explains "מלפפת" as meaning clinging to it and hugging it. And this word over there is a matter of 'clinging' to something...

Thus, in the quote you bring the word is to be understood as an 'clinging' or 'enveloping'

---

Another example that expands this idea is the midrash in [Devarim Rabbah 3:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.3.12?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) which discusses how Moshe was given the Torah. It writes there:

> אָמַר רֵישׁ לָקִישׁ הַתּוֹרָה שֶׁנִּתְּנָה לְמשֶׁה, עוֹרָהּ שֶׁל אֵשׁ לְבָנָה, וּכְתוּבָה בְּאֵשׁ שְׁחוֹרָה, וַחֲתוּמָה בְּאֵשׁ, **וּמְלֻפֶּפֶת בְּאֵשׁ**
>
> Resh Lakish said,"The Torah was given to Moshe, its skin of white fire and written with black fire, and sealed in fire, and **wrapped with fire**.

The [Etz Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org/Etz_Yosef_on_Devarim_Rabbah.3.12.10?lang=bi) over there helps to translate the text by saying "תרגום וחיבר ומלפף" - that the fire was literally 'hugging' and enveloped the Torah.